# Python Django 3.x template tags, галерея изображений, работа с объектами, тегами

Tags: python, html, css, django, веб-программирование

Пытаюсь разметить галерею для вебсайта. Дело в том, что при выводе циклом for объектов модели с базы данных (queryset'а) каждые четыре выведеных элемента нужно заключить в `<div class="column">`, что у меня сделать не получаеться ‍♂️

Вот, собственно, сам вывод элементов на экран:

```html
{% for i in photos %}
   <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

Нужно достичь вот такого результата:

```html
<div class="column">
   <img src="1.jpg">
   <img src="2.jpg">
   <img src="3.jpg">
   <img src="4.jpg">
</div>
<div class="column">
   <img src="5.jpg">
   <img src="6.jpg">
   <img src="7.jpg">
   <img src="8.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, вы можете использовать `{{ forloop }}`

Не уверен, что это самое рациональное решение, но я представляю это себе примерно так:

```html
{% for i in photos %}
   {% if forloop.first or forloop.counter % 4 == 0 %}<div class="column">{% endif %}

   <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" alt="">

   {% if forloop.last or forloop.counter % 4 == 0 %}</div>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Соответсвенно, каждую 4 итерацию цикла, Django подставит необходимые вам `<div></div>`, а также в начале и конце итерации цикла, что убережет вас от ошибки, когда картинок в queryset на последних итерациях не хватит для подстановки `</div>`

Пожалуйста, **проверьте возможность использования знака целочисленного деления `%` внутри тега шаблона**. Не уверен, что Django разрешит его. Если нет, то используйте библиотеку `django-mathfilters`. Тогда ваш шаблон будет выглядеть так:

```html
{% load mathfilters %}
...
{% for i in photos %}
   {% if forloop.first or forloop.counter|intdiv:4 == 0 %}<div class="column">{% endif %}

   <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" alt="">

   {% if forloop.last or forloop.counter|intdiv:4 == 0 %}</div>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Прочитайте подробнее в [официальной документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: Здраствуйте, решил действительно использовать forloop, но есть проблема с инсталяцией библиотеки django-mathfilters. Добавляю mathfilters в INSTALLED_APPS, делаю все по документации, но питон говорит. Unresolved library. Библиотеку действительно нужно установить, ведь знак % не работает в тегах

Comment: Из [официальной документации](https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/): установите библиотеку `pip install django-mathfilters`, а затем добавьте приложение в Django `INSTALLED_APPS = [..., 'mathfilters', ...]`

Comment: Понятненько, тогда попробую переустановить IDE, ведь все делаю корректно, но проблема остается, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй использовать
`{% cycle %}`. он последовательно выводит элементы из списка предоставленных значений, когда элементы заканчиваются начинает заново
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle

```
<div class="column">
{% for i in photos %}
  {% cycle '' '' '' '' '</div>' %} 
  {% cycle '' '' '' '' '<div class="column">' %}
   <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Что-то схожее, спасибо. Видел тэг на оф.сайте, но не разобрался как его использовать)

Comment: он достаточно прост для использования.(добавил описание в ответ)

Comment: Слишком сложно, проверка значения forloop.counter выглядела бы гораздо симпатичнее

Comment: в шаблонах вроде нельзя использовать `{% if forloop.counter % 4 == 0 %}` а без такого рода проверки нужно либо использовать дополнительные библиотеки, либо писать собственные фильтры. так что `cycle`, на мой взгляд, нормально подходит